# ParallelTable slower than Table in the presence of an Association?

Tags: list-manipulation, parallelization, associations

So after testing some things I am completely reformulating my problem.
First an example

```
as = Association[{2 -> 7, 3 -> 8, 4 -> 9, 5 -> 10, 6 -> 11}]
<|2 -> 7, 3 -> 8, 4 -> 9, 5 -> 10, 6 -> 11|>
calcF[x_, y_, Max_] := Sum[Lookup[as, x + y, 0], {i, 1, Max}]
doo[Max_] := Table[calcF[x, y, Max], {x, 1, 5}, {y, 1, 5}]

AbsoluteTiming[doo[50000]]
{0.539171, {{350000, 400000, 450000, 500000, 550000}, {400000, 450000,
500000, 550000, 0}, {450000, 500000, 550000, 0, 0}, {500000, 
550000, 0, 0, 0}, {550000, 0, 0, 0, 0}}}

doo[Max_] := ParallelTable[calcF[x, y, Max], {x, 1, 5}, {y, 1, 5}]

AbsoluteTiming[doo[50000]]
{2.45135, {{350000, 400000, 450000, 500000, 550000}, {400000, 450000, 
500000, 550000, 0}, {450000, 500000, 550000, 0, 0}, {500000, 
550000, 0, 0, 0}, {550000, 0, 0, 0, 0}}}

ls = {0, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0}
{0, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0}
malcF[x_, y_, Max_] := Sum[ls[[x + y]], {i, 1, Max}]
foo[Max_] := Table[malcF[x, y, Max], {x, 1, 5}, {y, 1, 5}]

AbsoluteTiming[foo[50000]]
{0.07679, {{350000, 400000, 450000, 500000, 550000}, {400000, 450000, 
500000, 550000, 0}, {450000, 500000, 550000, 0, 0}, {500000, 
550000, 0, 0, 0}, {550000, 0, 0, 0, 0}}}

foo[Max_] := ParallelTable[malcF[x, y, Max], {x, 1, 5}, {y, 1, 5}]

AbsoluteTiming[foo[50000]]
{0.032803, {{350000, 400000, 450000, 500000, 550000}, {400000, 450000,
500000, 550000, 0}, {450000, 500000, 550000, 0, 0}, {500000, 
550000, 0, 0, 0}, {550000, 0, 0, 0, 0}}}
```

So, from this it seems like `ParallelTable` has some issue with an `Association`, as it performs slower than `Table`. Is this behaviour expected? Is it a bug and can I get over it somehow?

Forgot to mention, in case it matters - my laptop has 4 cores that are hyper-threaded, but I have stuck with the default Mathematica setting to launch 4 kernels for parallel computations.

The reason I want to use an `Association` is because in my actual calculation `ls` will be a massive 5-dimensional `Table` with hundreds of millions of elements (thus taking all my RAM), but 95% of them will be  zeroes. Therefore, I want to replace it with an `Association` that will have only non-zero terms and will thus be much smaller, hence allowing me to perform the calculation.

Comment: You haven't given enough details, i.e. a working example of the problem, to enable anyone to help.

Comment: @Ymareth I added more information. My code is too long to include everything - especially `alternativeSum`

Comment: User, have you attempted to create a minimum working example?  If `Association` doesn't work with `ParallelTable` *generally* it should be possible to demonstrate it in only a few lines of code.  If not there may be a contributing factor that also needs to be discovered.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I created a minimal example and it seems to be working well, so the problem is apparently in my code. I am in the process of updating my question, but it will take a lot of time

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a complete explanation, but some observations that may be helpful.

First, this behavior doesn't specifically have to do with `Association`, since you see a similar slow-down when parallelizing using a plain old list of rules:

```
rules = {2 -> 7, 3 -> 8, 4 -> 9, 5 -> 10, 6 -> 11, _ -> 0};
calcF[x_, y_, Max_] := Sum[x + y /. rules, {i, 1, Max}]
First@AbsoluteTiming[Table[calcF[x, y, 50000], {x, 1, 5}, {y, 1, 5}]]
First@AbsoluteTiming[ParallelTable[calcF[x, y, 50000], {x, 1, 5}, {y, 1, 5}]]
(* 1.00533 *)
(* 1.91048 *)
```

On the other hand, it does seem to have to do with the many repeated replacements or lookups. If instead of using `Sum`, we make a list of the entries to be replaced, do one replacement operation, and then `Total` the result, there is a parallel speed-up. For example, using `Association`:

```
as = Association[{2 -> 7, 3 -> 8, 4 -> 9, 5 -> 10, 6 -> 11}];
calcF[x_, y_, Max_] := Total[Lookup[as, Table[x + y, {i, 1, Max}], 0]]
First@AbsoluteTiming[Table[calcF[x, y, 50000], {x, 1, 5}, {y, 1, 5}]]
First@AbsoluteTiming[ParallelTable[calcF[x, y, 50000], {x, 1, 5}, {y, 1, 5}]]
(* 0.195367 *)
(* 0.084041 *)
```

I'm no expert, but I might guess that when doing many repeated lookups, most of the time is spent retrieving values from memory, so multiple cores aren't going to help.

Also, to directly translate your original matrix-based method to the sparse case you can use [`SparseArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html), which is designed for exactly this purpose:

```
spls = SparseArray[{0, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0}];
malcF[x_, y_, Max_] := Sum[spls[[x + y]], {i, 1, Max}]
First@AbsoluteTiming[Table[malcF[x, y, 50000], {x, 1, 5}, {y, 1, 5}]]
First@AbsoluteTiming[ParallelTable[malcF[x, y, 50000], {x, 1, 5}, {y, 1, 5}]]
(* 1.14774 *) 
(* 0.501875 *)
```

(Note that `SparseArray` can also be entered as a list of rules, like `Association`.) This is slower than the `Association` method, but if we again make a table and do all of the lookups at once, we get the fastest result of all:

```
malcF[x_, y_, Max_] := Total[spls[[Table[x + y, {i, 1, Max}]]]]
First@AbsoluteTiming[Table[malcF[x, y, 50000], {x, 1, 5}, {y, 1, 5}]]
First@AbsoluteTiming[ParallelTable[malcF[x, y, 50000], {x, 1, 5}, {y, 1, 5}]] 
(* 0.064648 *)
(* 0.028374 *)
```

Vectorizing operations using Listable functions in this way is often the best method of obtaining speedups in *Mathematica*.

Comment: I am currently trying to implement your alternative method for the `Association` (one replacement on a `Table`, then `Total`) in my code.

I assume that I need to have the matrix generated, in order to apply `SparseArray`. It is the generation of the massive 5D-table that I am trying to avoid, as I need to increase the size further and it just freezes my laptop from one point onwards. I can create the `Association` without the need of first creating the massive array, using [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84319/sow-only-if-different-from-zero) question.

Comment: @user1482714, Rather than assuming, you should check the [documentation for `SparseArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html), which shows that you can create it using a list of rules.

Comment: Yea, sorry, I found that after commenting. Unfortunatelly, `SparseArray` doesn't seem to be an option for me, as I need the unique keys in the `Association` and they were created with [Cantor Pairing function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function), so some of them have a value of a few millions, thus the `SparseArray` is huge as well.

Comment: @user1482714, Of course, use whatever method works best for you, but actually `SparseArray` should use much *less* memory than the equivalent `Association`, since it can use the fact that the keys are all integers and the values are all numeric (assuming that they are) to store the data very efficiently ("Packed array", see [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3500/8253)). As far as I can tell, `Association` can not do this.

Comment: I tried with a `SparseArray` as well - the dimensions/length (it is 1D) is extremely huge and this apparently seems to create some kind of a problem, as whenever I try to use it for some actual calculation (creating it is not a problem and checking its `Dimensions`), _Mathematica_  just clears all variables and everything and nothing happens.

Comment: @user1482714, Not sure why that's happening, but some operations with a `SparseArray` may force it to "unpack" its efficient internal storage, or in some cases even cause it to convert itself to a normal array, either of which would blow up the storage required. If that caused you to run out of memory it might crash the kernel. If you want to use `SparseArray` you could maybe ask a new Question about it, or you could go back to using `Association`.