# Actual bins used for Pearson Chi Square Test

Tags: probability-or-statistics, implementation-details

`PearsonChiSquareTest[data, dist]` computes bins for `data` as a step towards calculating the test statistic. For continuous distributions, the documentation describes the general [approach](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PearsonChiSquareTest.html#71523217). If I want to get the actual bins used, particularly for discrete distributions, can it be discovered?

Some code to get started:

```
SeedRandom[1];
dist = PoissonDistribution[1.5];
n = 100;
data = RandomVariate[dist, n];
testData = PearsonChiSquareTest[data, dist, "TestData"]
(* {3.31031, 0.507301}  *)
nbins = 2 n^(2/5) // Ceiling;
del = DeleteDuplicates[Quantile[dist, Range[0, 1, 1/nbins]]];
observedFrequency = BinCounts[data, {del}];
expectedFrequency = n*(CDF[dist, Most[del]] - CDF[dist, Most[del - 1]]);
chisq = Total[(observedFrequency - expectedFrequency)^2/expectedFrequency]
chisq == testData[[1]]
(* False *)
```

Comment: There is no mechanism I'm aware of to pull out the bins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### `` Statistics`GoodnessOfFitTestingDump`pearsonChiSquareTest ``

Key calculations for `PearsonChiSquareTest` are performed inside the function `` Statistics`GoodnessOfFitTestingDump`pearsonChiSquareTest ``.

[image]

```
SeedRandom[1];
mp = MachinePrecision;
dist = PoissonDistribution[1.5];
n = 100;
data = RandomVariate[dist, n];
testData = PearsonChiSquareTest[data, dist, "TestData"]
```

> {3.31031, 0.507301}

With the input (`data, null distribution, precision, "SampleToNull"`) it returns the Pearson test statistic and the observed counts:

```
Statistics`GoodnessOfFitTestingDump`pearsonChiSquareTest[data, dist,  mp, "SampleToNull"]
```

> {3.31031, {25, 36, 27, 8, 4}}

The following lines are the relevant parts of the code for discrete univariate distributions:

```
Statistics`Library`DiscreteUnivariateDistributionQ[dist]
```

> True

**Bins**

```
nbins = Statistics`GoodnessOfFitTestingDump`iOptimalBinCount[n]
```

> 13

```
bins = Quiet[N[Sort[Quantile[dist, N[Range[0, 1, 1/nbins], mp]], Less], mp]];
bins = bins + N[1/2, mp];
bins[[1]] = bins[[1]] - 1;
bins
```

> {-0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 3.5, 3.5, 18.5}

**Frequencies:**

```
cdfs = Statistics`GoodnessOfFitTestingDump`iCDF[dist, bins];
cdfs = Rest[cdfs] - Most[cdfs];
exp = N[n cdfs, MachinePrecision]
```

> {22.313, 0., 33.4695, 0., 0., 0., 0., 25.1021, 0., 0., 12.5511, 0., 6.56425}

```
obs = (Length[Cases[data, x_ /; x < #1]] &) /@ bins;
obs = Rest[obs] - Most[obs]
```

> {25, 0, 36, 0, 0, 0, 0, 27, 0, 0, 8, 0, 4}

```
locs = Position[exp, 0 | 0.];
exp = Delete[exp, locs]
```

> {22.313, 33.4695, 25.1021, 12.5511, 6.56425}

```
obs = Delete[obs, locs]
```

> {25, 36, 27, 8, 4}

```
Total[ (obs - exp)^2/exp]
```

> 3.31031

Comment: How do you find the relevant internal functions?

Comment: @Ian, you might want to see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1742).

Comment: @Ian, i usually use the poor-man's one-liner , e.g, ``?? *`*earson*``, to search. If  you are lucky you get  a short list of  results. If a function `foo`  is `ReadProtected`, use `ClearAttributes[foo, ReadProtected]` then try `?? foo` to see the code.

Comment: @kguler: I should preface my statements with "No documented" from now on - +1 for another enlightening internals answer.

Comment: @ciao, thank you for the vote.