# How does Rescale[] handle infinities?

Tags: functions, nonlinear

[`Rescale`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Rescale.html) appears to be a simple function.  It just does a simple linear $y = a x + b$ type rescaling of the values:

```
Rescale@Range[0, 10]
(* {0, 1/10, 1/5, 3/10, 2/5, 1/2, 3/5, 7/10, 4/5, 9/10, 1} *)
```

Or does it?  The documentation never says that it's *linear*.  What happens if the input has an infinite quantity?

```
Rescale[Prepend[Range[10], -Infinity]]
(* {0, 1/10, 1/9, 1/8, 1/7, 1/6, 1/5, 1/4, 1/3, 1/2, 1} *)

ListPlot[%]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

That's a little strange.  The output numbers are no longer equispaced.

With both $-\infty$ and $\infty$ present, we get things like

```
Rescale[{-Infinity, 0, 1, 2, Infinity}]
(* {0, 1/2, 1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[5]), 1/Sqrt[2], 1} *)
```

I would have expected some error messages about indeterminate results instead.

**What does `Rescale` do when infinities are present?  What's the justification for this behaviour?  Where is it documented?**

We should note that `Rescale[list]` is really `Rescale[list, {Min[list], Max[list]}]`, so it's in fact the infinities in the second argument that trigger this.  Such behaviour is acceptable if it's documented and if it's explicitly requested by putting infinities in the second argument.  But in my situation an infinite quantity slipped into the input only by accident, and I suddenly started getting unexpected strange results.

Comment: Very surprising. Have a look at the results of `Rescale[x, {a, ∞}]`, `Rescale[x, {-∞, b}]`, and `Rescale[x, {-∞, ∞}]`… how did you encounter this?

Comment: @J.M. Actually it's very boring: 1. make visualization functions that needs to transform numbers to colours, thus it needs to rescale to $[0,1]$ 2. try to visualize the logarithm of some data and forget to remove the zeros, which introduces `-Infinity` 3. stare at the result and be surprised about how the colours have just changed

Comment: Okay, that's the application I did have in mind. I tried the three I gave in my comment in Alpha; quite a surprise!

Comment: @J.M. Does that make any sense to you, especially the last one?  They seem to be fairly arbitrary choices, some others could work just as well for transforming $\infty$ to 0 or 1.

Comment: The last one works (have a look at its Taylor expansion), but conventionally I've tended to use the logistic function (see e.g. the Gaussian curvature coloring question I answered a while back), arctangent, or hyperbolic tangent myself. I'd say the choices do seem rather arbitrary.

Comment: It's a bit disturbing that `Rescale` automatically and unexpectedly (no warning!) switches algorithm if a single Infinity creeps into the input, while functions where infinities don't matter at all, such as `DiagonalMatrix`, error out: try `DiagonalMatrix[{-Infinity, 0}]`, it fails.  The truly nonsensical `DiagonalMatrix[{"asd", Graphics@Circle[]}]` on the other hand works.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answers of the original questions by Szabolcs:

> What does Rescale do when infinities are present? What's the justification for this behaviour? Where is it documented?

were guessed correctly with the comment:

> If I may be allowed to speculate, these were picked because they do the job advertised and are "conveniently" algebraic. They certainly work splendidly when used as variable substitutions for integrals with infinite limits. – J. M.

I programmed `Rescale` in the *Mathematica* kernel both in C and in top level. Originally, the request for `Rescale` was derived from image manipulation cases in FrontEnd. It is obviously useful otherwise. I wanted the `Rescale` functionality for top level implementation of integration algorithms in the `NIntegrate` framework. See the numerous uses of `Rescale` in the advanced `NIntegrate` documentation. For example, in [NIntegrate Integration Strategies](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html).

Generally speaking, within `NIntegrate`'s framework I wanted to use `Rescale` for converting infinite regions and for handling singularities.

After some discussions the `Rescale` transformations of ranges with `Infinity` were left implemented but undocumented. The main reasons being that (1) there is a good adherence with `Rescale` for finite intervals, and (2) there are too many such mathematical transformations and the selection of the particular one implemented in `Rescale` is hard to explain.

(Sorry for my delayed reply. I found this question by accident today.)

---

**Edit**

Here is some code that shows `Rescale` formulas for different combinations of ranges:

```
 r1pairs = {{a, b}, {-∞, b}, {a, ∞}, {a, -∞}, {-∞, ∞}};
r2pairs = {{c, d}, {-∞, d}, {c, ∞}, {c, -∞}, {-∞, ∞}};
tbl = Table[Simplify @ Rescale[x, r1, r2], {r1, r1pairs}, {r2, r2pairs}];
Grid[Prepend[MapThread[Prepend, {tbl, r1pairs}], 
  Prepend[r2pairs, ""]], Alignment -> Left, Dividers -> All, 
 Background -> {{GrayLevel[0.95], White}, {GrayLevel[0.95], White}}]
```

The result should be something like this:

[image: Rescale table]

(The ranges that are the second `Rescale` argument are given in the first column; the ranges that are the third `Rescale` argument are given on the first row.)

Comment: Anton, welcome to Mathematica.StackExchange and thank you for your contribution!

Comment: @Anton From the other answers it is not immediately clear what the transformation `Rescale` uses for ranges with `Infinity`. Could you please include the formula into your answer for convenience?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks!

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I added a table with formulas and code that generates it. (Can be executed for other ranges of interest.)

Answer (score 9):

This functionality is undocumented, but evident when [`Spelunk`ing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15948/26956):

```
Rescale[x, {DirectedInfinity[-1], DirectedInfinity[1]}]
(* (-2 + x + Sqrt[4 + x^2])/(2 x) *)
```

`Rescale[x, {-Infinity, Infinity}]` is equivalent to `Rescale[x, {-Infinity, Infinity}, {0, 1}]`. The relevant entry in the definition when spelunking:

```
Needs["Spelunk`"]
Spelunk[Rescale]
```

This returns a number of replacement rules for `Rescale` with infinities. The relevant rule for my example is:

> ```
> Rescale[x_, {DirectedInfinity[d1_], 
>     DirectedInfinity[d2_]}, {a : Except[_DirectedInfinity], 
>     b : Except[_DirectedInfinity]}] /; ! 
>    TrueQ[{d1, d2} == {-1, 1} || {d1, d2} == {1, -1}] := 
>  Block[{valid, res}, 
>          valid = System`Dump`validDoublyInfiniteComplexRangeQ[d1, d2];
>     If[valid, 
>    res = Rescale[x/(d2/Abs[d2]), {-\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {a, b}]];
>     res /; valid]
> ```

As you can see, however, the rule applies if, and only if, the infinities are not "negative-to-positive" or "positive-to-negative". Failing that, the offset in their direction is accounted for as a complex multiplier added to `x` and the problem is reduced to rescaling a negative-to-positive infinity.

It seems, that `Rescale` reduces every problem with infinities to a problem such as `Rescale[x, {-Infinity, Infinity}, {0, 1}]` or similar. There is not an explicit rule, however, listed for this problem. It seems, that somewhere deeper down, there is a built-in rule that does not show up with `Spelunk` that says "once we have reduced our problem to `Rescale[x, {-Infinity, Infinity}, {0, 1}]`, return `(-2 + x + Sqrt[4 + x^2])/(2 x)`. This is made evident by

```
Trace[Rescale[x, {-\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]]
```

> ```
> ... Rescale[x, {-\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}], (-2 + x + Sqrt[4 + x^2])/(2 x)
> ```

So in a few words, almost all of the functionality with infinities is "documented" (in a hidden way, accessible only through spelunking), *except* the final transformations from the basic cases such as the one I described to the functions of `x`, which does not even show up in the output of `Spelunk`.

Comment: Have you tried `Trace[]`-ing the two other examples in my first comment? What comes up?

Comment: @J.M. Nothing.  I have actually looked at the definition before posting here, noticed that the main case is not accessible, and tried tracing with `TraceInternal`.  I wouldn't really say "code can be decompiled sans comments or formatting" is equivalent to "documented".

Comment: @Szabolcs, "…'code can be decompiled sans comments or formatting' is equivalent to 'documented'…" - I don't consider 'em equivalent either. One would hope something along the lines of "…if the lower or upper limit is a `DirectedInfinity[]`, `Rescale[]` uses a different formula…" was in the docs. Feh…

Comment: If I may be allowed to speculate, these were picked because they do the job advertised and are "conveniently" algebraic. They certainly work splendidly when used as variable substitutions for integrals with infinite limits.

Comment: @Szabolcs regarding *"code can be decompiled sans comments or formatting" is equivalent to "documented".* I figured it's appropriate to add sarcastic quotation marks to my use of the word documented. The final replacement rules are even less "documented" though. It's a shame, rescaling infinite ranges is very useful for `NDSolve` with infinite ranges.