# How to get the meaning of a Mathematica symbol you don't know ?

Tags: symbols

I would like to know how can I get help on a Mathematica symbol that I don't know ?
There is often this case when I read some codes from forum or collegues.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just type a question mark before the command and hit enter.  Or highlight the symbol and hit F1

Comment: minor correction: highlight (place the cursor on, or select, the symbol or term you're interested in) and press `F1` (the function-1 key) on your keyboard. Also note that the Help documentation built into Mathematica is excellent (allows searching on symbols, too), and that it is also completely reproduced online [reference.wolfram.com](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/)

Comment: There is a general list: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/30771

Comment: I am sorely tempted to close this as "easily found in the documentation"…

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. But what if you can't find the documentation? :-D

Comment: More seriously, there's a fantastic package here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15948/26956 although I don't think, this is exactly as deep as the OP wanted to go (or rather, vice-versa).

Comment: note a "symbol that I don't know" isn't necessarily a documented thing so `F1` may not work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users)

Answer (score 4):

In{1};= ?FindFit [Shift+Enter]

[image]

Then click the >>> at the bottom to expand the text. Placing the MMA command after the ? will give you the description and usage.