# What is the meaning of some of the capital letters?

Tags: options, properties

One can get capital letters as follows

```
 ToExpression@(Capitalize /@ Alphabet[])
```

[image]

We know that E,I,N,D are functions of Mathematica but what about K,C,O? they have no options and FullDefinition shows that they are protected only. why is that ?

[image]

Comment: For `C` and `O` hitting F1 leads to the answer.

Comment: And actually `Information` solves them all.

Comment: closely related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92368/5478

Comment: @Kuba thanks for the info

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation (MMA 12):

> C[i]
>   is the default form for the i[Null][Null]^th parameter or constant generated in representing the results of various symbolic computations.
>
> O[x]^n 
>   represents a term of order x^n.

no idea about K, but I can actually use it as a symbol (it's not protected).