# Searching for literal strings with TextSearch

Tags: text, searching

The documentation indicates that `TextSearch` can be used to look for a "literal string" inside documents, but it appears Mathematica may be applying a regex-style word boundary rule under the hood. Is it possible to get around this?

```
TextSearch["path/to/logs/", "driver_1_2015-08-03.csv"]
```

> TextSearch::invqs: Query string "driver_1_2015-08-03.csv" is not a word or sequence of words. >>

Comment: note this is new in 10.2 and marked "Experimental"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd say that the acceptable forms of the query string are much more limited than the documentation lets on. In fairness though, [`TextSearch`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TextSearch.html) is marked [[Experimental]] in the docs, so it may very well be in a state of flux and you would probably *not* want to use it for anything critical.

Having said that, some [spelunking](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1742/) of the definition of `TextSearch` reveals that the query string is first passed to an implementation `iTextSearch` function, which passes it to a `CompileQuery` function, which in turn passes it to a `comp` intermediate function with multiple definitions.

In the case of a single string query like yours, the matching definition of `comp` is:

```
comp[s_String] := compStr[StringTrim[ToLowerCase[s]]]
```

`StringTrim` and `ToLowerCase` are perfectly happy with your string and leave it unmodified.

`compStr` is where the problem lies, in my view. This is its definition:

```
compStr[s_] := Which[

  StringMatchQ[s, WordCharacter ..], 
        QString[s],

  StringMatchQ[s, (WordCharacter .. ~~ Whitespace) .. ~~ WordCharacter ..], 
        QIntersection[QString /@ StringSplit[s]],

  True, 
        Message[TextSearch::invqs, s]; Throw[$Failed];
]
```

Strings like yours containing characters beyond word characters and whitespaces (i.e. spaces, tabs, and newlines) won't match any of those patterns, so the `Which` will select the default `True` branch, throwing the `TextSearch::invqs` message you see and failing out.

---

A rather **brutal workaround** is to redefine the `compStr` function to get around the check:

```
Clear[TextSearch`IndexSearch`PackagePrivate`compStr]

TextSearch`IndexSearch`PackagePrivate`compStr[s_] :=
  Which[
   StringMatchQ[s, (WordCharacter .. ~~ Whitespace) .. ~~ WordCharacter ..],
     TextSearch`IndexSearch`PackagePrivate`QIntersection[TextSearch`IndexSearch`PackagePrivate`QString /@ StringSplit[s]],

   StringQ[s],
     TextSearch`IndexSearch`PackagePrivate`QString[s],

   True,
     Message[TextSearch::invqs, s]; Throw[$Failed]
]
```

After the redefinition, the following call to `TextSearch` seemed to work fine:

```
TextSearch["sandbox", "ala_a"]
```

[image: Output of textsearch]

The result is correct as well: the file returned is indeed the only one in the folder to contain the "ala_a" string.