# What are the default Frame / Axes styles and how can I find them?

Tags: plotting, graphics, style

I'm sure this must have been asked before but I am unable to find anything here on SE or on Google in general.

I simply want to know what the default color and thickness are for a `Frame` on a `Plot` and for the `Axes`.

Looking in the help seems to send me down a rabbit hole of,

> The default style of axes is specified by the option `DefaultAxesStyle`.
>
> For Graphics, the default setting is `DefaultAxesStyle->"GraphicsAxes"`

And although I can use `GraphicsAxes` as an option value, eg `FrameStyle->"GraphicsAxes"` I still can't discover what the actual shade of gray and line thickness that is. Are these deliberately hidden somewhere, or I am not looking hard enough?

Many thanks,

Comment: Have a look here [Is there a method to look inside at the internal code of Built-In functions?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/105052/is-there-a-method-to-look-inside-at-the-internal-code-of-built-in-functions/105054#105054), is this helpful?

Comment: Good question. If you look at `FullForm[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}, Frame->True]` or leave the `Frame` off, no head contains `AxesStyle` or `FrameStyle` so I also am stuck pondering what are the color and thickness of for the defaults "GraphicsAxes" and "GraphicsFrame".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hunting through the stylesheets is effective, but does not necessarily give you the current value being used if it has been modified. Instead, use

```
CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions , "GraphicsAxes"}]
(* {Arrowheads -> {}, LineColor -> GrayLevel[0.4], Thickness -> Absolute[0.2]} *)

CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions , "GraphicsFrame"}]
(* {LineColor -> GrayLevel[0.4], Thickness -> Absolute[0.5]} *)
```

Comment: Nice code! I just tried to help myself and applied `CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "FrameTicksStyle"}]` to get the values from a `ListDensityPlot`it brings `{}` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Kay if you notice, the query is not `"AxesStyle"` or `"FrameStyle"`, but `"GraphicsAxes"` and `"GraphicsFrame"`. Extrapolating from that, you're looking for `"GraphicsFrameTicks"`, not `"FrameTicksStyle"`, and you get `{ScriptLevel -> 1, LineColor -> GrayLevel[0.4]}`, in 10.4.

Comment: right! thank you!

Answer (score 9):

The styles "GraphicsAxes" and "GraphicsFrame" are defined in the stylesheet "Core.nb".

- To access to this file use the menu : format/edit stylesheet
- Then in the notebook that appears click on Default.nb
- In the new notebook that appears click on Core.nb
- Then the notebook core.nb appears.
- Go to section :"style for Mathematica System-specific Elements" and open it
- Go to the cell "default Box style" and open it
- Go to "Local definition for style Graphics"
- Select the cell "GraphicsAxes"
- Do Control-Shift-E (on Windows, otherwise you can use the menu :   Cell/ShowExpression)
- Then you see :

  `Cell[StyleData["GraphicsAxes"],
  Arrowheads->{},
  LineColor->GrayLevel[0.4],
  Thickness->Absolute[0.2]]`

This is the internal structure of the cell. One can see the settings for the style "GraphicsAxes"