# How to get information about DefaultStyle of axes, frame, colorfunction, etc

Tags: style

How can I find out the `DefaultStyle` of `Axes`, `Frames`, `PlotRangeClipping`, (just to name some of them), of `Plot`, `DensityPlot`, etc. and am I able to change them? If yes, how?

Comment: `Options[Plot]`, and maybe ``Charting`ResolvePlotTheme["Default", Plot]``. You can use `SetOptions[]` to change settings as seen fit. Classically, one used `FullGraphics[]` and `AbsoluteOptions[]`, but these have been broken since version 6.

Comment: See also here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/105082/what-are-the-default-frame-axes-styles-and-how-can-i-find-them

Comment: @Quantum_Oli - Looks like you were some days faster ^^