# Change `FrameStyle` defaults

Tags: plotting, graphics, style

[This question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/105082/what-are-the-default-frame-axes-styles-and-how-can-i-find-them) discusses how to find out the defaults are for `FrameStyle`.

How can these options be changed? For example, if we wanted `LineColor -> Black` and `Thickness -> Absolute[0.8]`, how can this be chaged?

Ideally, it would be good to change it for just a single notebook. Global would be fine too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`SetOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetOptions) on the notebook:

```
SetOptions[
    EvaluationNotebook[],
    GraphicsBoxOptions->{DefaultFrameStyle -> Directive[LineColor->Red,Thickness->Absolute[2]]}
]
```

I used [`Red`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Red) and `Absolute[2]` instead so that the effects are more noticeable. Also, note that I used [`Directive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Directive), so that the primitives apply to all four edges. If you want to customize individual edges, you would use the usual `{{left, right}, {bottom, top}}` syntax instead. Here's a very short animation:

[image]

Comment: Thanks; it works in the notebook. How to get it to also work on export to PDF? [I saw this previous answer but don't know what to change.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/160506/22432)