# Certainty of the New Vertex Name after using EdgeContract

Tags: graphs-and-networks, undocumented

It appears that when I use `EdgeContract` on an undirected graph, the vertex that is the result of contracting an edge is always named the smaller of the two vertices. So

```
VertexList@EdgeContract[g, UndirectedEdge[1,3]]
```

will no longer contain the vertex `3`. Is it guaranteed anywhere in the Mathematica documentation that this will always be the behavior of `EdgeContract` (at least on an undirected graph where we contract a single vertex)? I couldn't find any mention of this on the [documentation page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeContract.html) for `EdgeContract`. I would hate to be surprised by some subtly in how `EdgeContract` is implemented where it renames the vertices some other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, it is always the case that `EdgeContract` replaces the vertices appearing in the contracted edges with the "smallest" vertex.**

The function `EdgeContract` calls the function `` GraphComputation`GraphContractDump`edgeContract `` which takes the `Union` of the vertices appearing in the contracted edges (see the highlighted lines below) and calls `VertexContract`,

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

and

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Example:

```
VertexList[EdgeContract[Graph[{1 <-> 2, 3 <-> 1, 1 <-> 4, 1 <-> 5, 1 <-> 6, 1 <-> 7, 
    2 <-> 3, 2 <-> 7, 3 <-> 4, 5 <-> 4, 5 <-> 6, 6 <-> 7}],
  {UndirectedEdge[6, 7], UndirectedEdge[5, 4]}]]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4}

Temporarily replacing `Union` with `DeleteDuplicates` we get

```
Block[{Union = DeleteDuplicates}, 
 VertexList[EdgeContract[Graph[{1 <-> 2, 3 <-> 1, 1 <-> 4, 1 <-> 5, 1 <-> 6, 1 <-> 7, 
     2 <-> 3, 2 <-> 7, 3 <-> 4, 5 <-> 4, 5 <-> 6, 6 <-> 7}],  
    {UndirectedEdge[6, 7], UndirectedEdge[5, 4]}]]]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 6}

Note: See the answers by Simon Woods and Taliesin Beynon in [Spelunking tools](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1742/125) for useful ways to get the definitions of Mathematica functions.

Comment: Wow. Thank you very much.

Comment: @mapierce271, my pleasure. Thank you for the Accept.