# Why are CoefficientRules and MonomialList so slow?

Tags: performance-tuning, polynomials

Why is `CoefficientRules` so slow in this example (v10.2 on OS X 10.11.4)?

```
expr = Sum[x^i, {i, 1, 15}]^30;
CoefficientRules[expr/(expr + expr^2), y]; // AbsoluteTiming
MonomialList[expr/(expr + expr^2), y]; // AbsoluteTiming
CoefficientRules[Expand@(expr/(expr + expr^2)), y]; // AbsoluteTiming
CoefficientList[expr/(expr + expr^2), y]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* Out: 
    {1.83157, Null}
    {1.42334, Null}
    {8.48815, Null}
    {0.000063, Null}
*)
```

Note that it does not seem to be related to the similar issue that `Coefficient` does not always expand the expression. Also note that the expression to which `CoefficientRules[#, y] &` is applied does not actually contain `y`.

Is there any clever way of efficiently achieving the result of `CoefficientRules` or `MonomialList` without parsing the output of `CoefficientList` (as I want to generally be able to use this efficiently in the multivariate case)?

Comment: Am I missing something here? `expr/(expr + expr^2)` does not result in a polynomial, which is what's expected for the first argument of those functions.

Comment: @ciao it is not a polynomial in x, but it is a zero degree polynomial in y, and is correctly processed by all these functions

Comment: What version of Mathematica are you using?  On v8, my computer takes 270 seconds to finish `CoefficientRules[Expand@#,y]&` (but only 1 second to do the first two).  Timings on v9 are similar to yours.  On v10.3, it takes 15 seconds to do first three (regression?) on 10.4 it takes 17 seconds on the first three (further regression).

Comment: @QuantumDot, I'm actually using v10.2. When you say 15 seconds to do the first three, do you mean each of them individually? If so, it is somewhat strange that the one with `Expand` is taking the same time as the other two.

Comment: Peter, @QuantumDot, I wonder if you could repeat the measurements using `AbsoluteTiming`, rather than `Timing`. The latter may be confusing sometimes and it is hard to compare different operating systems / CPU architectures (see Details on AbsoluteTiming, "On certain computer systems with multiple CPUs, the Wolfram Language kernel may sometimes spawn additional threads on different CPUs. On some operating systems, Timing may ignore these additional threads. On other operating systems, it may give the total time spent in all threads, which may exceed the result from AbsoluteTiming.").

Comment: On MMA 10.4, Win7-64, using `AbsoluteTiming`, it takes roughly 9s to execute each of the first three lines, and 38ms for the last.

Comment: @PeterKravchuk - Mea culpa, I'd read the `y` as `x` in my quick glance...

Answer (score 5):

Not an answer, but just a collection of results on my computer (Mac OS X 11.4).

The timings are in seconds as reported by `AbsoluteTiming`.  They are in the same order as the test cases provided by OP

On Mathematica 8: `-- {1.44,  1.33, 271.7,  0.000066}`

On Mathematica 9: `-- {0.62,  0.61,   9.00, 0.00012}`

On Mathematica 10.3 : `{8.82,  8.78,   8.62, 0.00006}`

On Mathematica 10.4 : `{8.71,  8.93,   8.83, 0.00011}`

On Mathematica 11.0: `{8.04,  8.17,   8.24, 0.00023}`

**On Mathematica 11.2**: `{8.55,  8.52,   8.38, 0.0056}`

**Edit**: the behavior continues through version 11.2.0

Comment: @MarcoB v10.2, OS X El Cap. 10.11.4, `AbsoluteTiming` gives `{1.83, 1.42, 8.48, 0.00006}`

Answer (score 4):

This is not an answer.  But I can pinpoint the origin of performance regression of `CoefficientRules` from version 9.0 to 10.3.  This requires [`Spelunk`ing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15948/26956) tools.

After calling `CoefficientRules` to initialize it, run

```
<< Spelunk`
Spelunk[CoefficientRules]
```

[image: CoefficientRules code]

This code is identical in v9 and v10.  Now *spelunk* deeper by inspecting `` GroebnerBasis`DTL ``, accessed by clicking on one of the `DTL` buttons in the code above.

The code for `DTL` is longer.  But two-thirds of the way down, is the first call to `` GroebnerBasis`DistributedTermsList `` (also a button).  That line has been changed from version 9 to 10.  In version 9, it is:

[image: Version 9 DTL code]

but in version 10, they have slipped in a call to `Expand` (which I highlighted for clarity):

[image: Version 10 DTL code]

This extra `Expand` causes the performance degradation for large polynomials.  Presumably, this was added because a bug was found causing `DTL` to return an incorrect result in certain cases without `Expand`ing the input polynomial.

---

It seems like `` GroebnerBasis`DistributedTermsList `` is the faster low-level function, and `CoefficientRules` has a bunch of overhead.  In principle, if you know the precise form of the input polynomial along with the relevant variables, it should be possible to directly make the call to `` GroebnerBasis`DistributedTermsList `` in your code.

Comment: I do recall there was a bug fix along those lines, so this is indeed probably what happened. A plausible improvement I need to consider is a precheck whether the input is already explicitly polynomial in the given variables.