# Information (??) of function defined in Package return the function with long name of variables

Tags: packages

When I call Information of a function defined in Package I get always the result that shows the function with full name Private variables.

For example:

```
BeginPackage["test`"];

testFunction::usage="testFunction";
testMean::usage="data";

Begin["`Private`"];

testFunction[n_]:=Module[{data},data=RandomReal[10,{n,2}];
testMean=Mean[data]];

End[];

EndPackage[];
```

once I load the Package and enter:

```
?? testFunction
```

I get this result which shows clearly that the Private variable are shown in full name.

[image]

what to do to just view the name of the variables without its context.

Thank you

Comment: I marked this as a duplicate of the question happy fish linked to as it surely looks like one to me.  If you feel that you need something else please edit your question to reference that one and explain how your requirements differ.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard it is a complete duplicate .)

Answer (score 1):

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"];
PrintDefinitions[testFunction]
```

More methods here: [1742](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1742/what-is-the-most-convenient-way-to-read-definitions-of-in-memory-symbols-when-we)