# FillingStyle->{None,Automatic} gives unexpected results?

Tags: plotting, graphics, syntax, options

```
Plot[1 - x^2, {x, -1.5, 1.5},
 Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> {None, Automatic}]
```

produces an outcomes I find unexpected:

[image: unexpected fill]

In contrast,

```
Plot[1 - x^2, {x, -1.5, 1.5},
 Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> {None, LightBlue}]
```

produces the expected outcome:

[image: expected fill]

Have I misunderstood the meaning of `Automatic` in this setting?  That is, why would I not see the same area shaded in both cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to me that `Automatic` is not a valid input at that level of the option specification.  Consider that this generates the same output:

```
Plot[1 - x^2, {x, -1.5, 1.5}
 , Filling -> Axis
 , FillingStyle -> {None, "bad input"}
]
```

[image]

---

#### Spelunking

I was not able to find any great revelations, but since Alan wrote: *"But I'm hoping Mr. Wizard will still offer some insights as to why we would be driven to such hackishness"* I thought I should at least try to look at the implementation behind this behavior.  I used [`PrintDefinitions` from the GeneralUtilities package](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78898/121) and [`Trace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trace.html).  From:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
PrintDefinitions @ System`ProtoPlotDump`iPlot
```

I found that (in version 10.1.0) the `FillingStyle` option value is handed off (as `fillingstyle`) to the internal function `` Charting`customFillingStyle `` with the call:

```
If[filling === None, None, 
 Charting`customFillingStyle[filling, plotstyle, defaultstyle, fillingstyle, 
   System`ProtoPlotDump`$FillingStyleOpacity][Length[modelData["Expressions"]], 
  Plot]]
```

Spelunking that (`` PrintDefinitions @ Charting`customFillingStyle ``) reveals definitions for explicit `Automatic` arguments which would not match `{None, Automatic}`, e.g.:

```
Charting`customFillingStyle[Automatic | Axis, Charting`CommonDump`pstyle_, 
  Charting`CommonDump`dpstyle_, Automatic, Charting`CommonDump`opacity_] := . . .
```

Other values are again handed off, this time to as the second parameter of `` Charting`CommonDump`combinePnFStyle ``.  Reading that definition (`` PrintDefinitions @ Charting`CommonDump`combinePnFStyle ``) shows that this function is expecting a color (`_?ColorQ`) or Graphics directive (`` _?Charting`generalDirective ``), or a `List` which contains either colors, directives, or None, e.g. `{_?(MatchQ[#1, Except[_Rule, _?ColorQ | None]] &) ..}`.  There is no provision for `Automatic` at this level of the program. If the argument does not match one of the patterns above is effectively dropped by the final definition in which the second parameter is unnamed and unused:

```
Charting`CommonDump`combinePnFStyle[_, _, opacity_, i_] := 
  Charting`padList[
   Charting`ConstructDirective[ColorData[1][i], 
    If[opacity === {}, {}, Opacity[opacity]]], 2];
```

What I first wrote is borne out: `Automatic` is not a valid input as the element of a `List` within the option value of `FillingStyle`; it is only valid as the complete option value.  I cannot explain this design choice, only offer this analysis of the existing program code.  Using `FillingStyle -> {None, Opacity[0.2]}` may seem like a hack but it is concise and effective.

Comment: Yes.
i. Does it seem "right" that `Automatic` would be invalid here?
ii. How then is one supposed to get the current default fill color?

Comment: @Alan Let me think about both points and get back to you.

Comment: @Alan Although a bit award, Plot[1 - x^2, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, Filling -> Axis, 
 FillingStyle -> {None, Directive[ColorData[97], Opacity[.2]]}]`, seems to work.

Comment: @Alan Or, `Plot[1 - x^2, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, Filling -> Axis, 
 FillingStyle -> {None, Opacity[.2]}]`

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thanks for pointing out the opacity hack.  (Also to Edmund and Chip.)  But I'm hoping Mr. Wizard will still offer some insights as to why we would be driven to such hackishness.

Comment: @Alan I did my best to give a deeper answer.  I am sorry if you do not find it satisfying.  Nevertheless thanks for the Accept.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard This is also a remarkable instruction on how I could ask a more precise question next time.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To get the current colour you can *hack* it with `FillingStyle -> {Opacity[0], Opacity[1]}`.

```
Plot[1 - x^2, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> {Opacity[0], Opacity[1]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think you want `{Opacity[0], Opacity[0.2]}` to get the default result.

Answer (score 1):

```
Plot[1 - x^2, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> {None, LightGray}]
```

fills `None` below the axis and `LightGrey` above the axis, as shown in the question.

On the other hand, `Automatic` seems to override `None` in

```
Plot[1 - x^2, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> {None, Automatic}]
```

causing a `Filling` of `Blue` throughout, just as in

```
Plot[1 - x^2, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> {Automatic}]
```

To obtain `LightGrey` throughout, use

```
Plot[1 - x^2, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> LightGray]
```

[image]

or to obtain `Blue` only in the center section, use

```
Plot[1 - x^2, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> {None, Blue}]
```

[image]

Comment: My question is whether there is a bug in the handling of `Automatic`, or have I misunderstood it somehow.

Comment: Apparently, anything combined with `Automatic` yields the first plot in your question,.for instance, `FillingStyle -> {Red, Automatic}`.  I would call this a bug, but others might describe it simply as inadequate documentation.

Comment: Note that `Plot[1 - x^2, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, Filling -> Axis, 
 FillingStyle -> {Red, White, Blue}]` also yields the first plot in your question.  This suggests that any instance of incorrect syntax reverts to `{Automatic}`.  Perhaps, `FillingStyle` considers `{None, Automatic}` as bad syntax, although the documentation does not say so.