# Sorting list of Chinese strings

Tags: string-manipulation, sorting

I have a list of Chinese strings; for example, like this:

```
list1 = StringPartition[Import["http://text-share.com/view/c652fa55", "Data"][[-1]], 4]
```

Now I want to sort it according to Chinese alphabetical order.

There are two equivalent ways, but they differ in efficiency.

The faster way is

```
AlphabeticSort[new, Entity["Language", "ChineseMandarin"]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*{0.00261, Null}*)
```

a much slower way is

```
SortBy[new, Transliterate]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*{0.465786, Null}*)
```

However, what if my data is like this:

```
list2 = Transpose[{list1, Range @ Length @ list1}];
```

I want to sort this list by the Chinese strings in it. `SortBy[list2, Transliterate @ #[[1]] &]` is definitely slow. `AlphabeticOrder` is also slow:

```
Sort[list2, 
   AlphabeticOrder[#1[[1]], #2[[1]], 
     Entity["Language", "ChineseMandarin"]]>=0 &]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*{0.512303, Null}*)
```

Is it possible to use `AlphabeticSort` to sort an arbitrary list to get maximum efficiency?

Answer (score 6):

Spelunking the code of `AlphabeticSort[]` reveals its mechanism: it generates an index list (similar to `Ordering[]`) that is then used to sort the original list of strings. Extracting the relevant internal code for constructing this index list, we have:

```
list1 = StringPartition[Import["http://text-share.com/view/c652fa55", "Data"][[-1]], 4];
list2 = Transpose[{list1, Range @ Length @ list1}];

lang = "ChineseMandarin";
args = Prepend[System`AlphabeticOrderDump`convertOptionsToStringSortArguments[
               "Language" -> lang, "MainHeader" -> AlphabeticSort], 
               System`AlphabeticOrderDump`getCollatorID[lang]];
idx = System`AlphabeticOrderDump`callStringsOrderingFunction[{list2[[All, 1]],
                                                              Sequence @@ args}];
list2[[idx]]
```

Comment: Wow, this is so advanced! I am also interested in the way you Spelunking the code.

Comment: I used `PrintDefinitions[]`. See [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78898).

Comment: Great tool ! Thanks. But how do you know those functions are under ``System`AlphabeticOrderDump``?

Comment: You can mouse over a function name in the definition to see its full name with the contexts.

Comment: That is interesting! Thank you so much! : )

Comment: Spelunking is an interesting word I have never seen in English. In Germany we use the word "Spelunke" for a restaurant or inn of dubious reputation. The song title "Honky tonk woman" is sometimes translated into German as "Spelunkenweib". It is of latin/greek origin and refers to a cave.

Comment: @Dr., Hintze, that is more or less the context of it; the original meaning was "exploring a cave", and now one can draw parallels between exploring unknown corners of a cave and exploring the deep code underbelly of *Mathematica*... the English equivalent of your *Spelunke* would be "hole in the wall"; so, effectively a cave, too!

Comment: @J.M. Hi, J.M. I got a problem when I run this code today. It warns me "Throw::nocatch: Uncaught Throw[AlphabeticOrderUnevaluatedTag,AlphabeticOrderCatchThrowTag] returned to top level." I don't understand why, because several days ago , it works fine. Do you know what is wrong?

Comment: Have you tried restarting your *Mathematica* session, @matheorem?

Comment: @J.M. yes, I have closed it and restart it. So your mathematica has no such warning?

Comment: Hmm. Try this, @matheorem: in a fresh session, call `AlphabeticSort[list, "ChineseMandarin"]` first for some short `list` with Mandarin strings. Then, run the code that I have. I suspect that this is because these internal functions are not loaded until `AlphabeticSort[]` is called first.

Comment: @J.M. Great! It works! You are so clever! Thank you! : )