# Implementation of ShearingMatrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, implementation-details, geometric-transform

How does Mathematica implement [`ShearingMatrix`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ShearingMatrix.html)?

In other words given the parameters $\theta$, $n$ and $v$, what is the formula behind it?

Comment: `ShearingMatrix` evaluates for symbolic inputs. While it won't display the general formula used, it will show its particular expression for a given dimension. For instance in 2D, one can evaluate `ShearingMatrix[\[Theta], {u1, u2}, {v1, v2}]`.

Comment: The general formula can be found with some spelunking: ``<<GeneralUtilities`; PrintDefinitions[ShearingMatrix]``.

Comment: @xavier This doesn't seem to work in Mathematica 10. It does nothing.

Comment: Ah OK, `PrintDefinitions` is from 10.1. You could have a look [there](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1742/what-is-the-most-convenient-way-to-read-definitions-of-in-memory-symbols-when-we) for other spelunking tools.

Comment: @xavier I tried this in 10.1 and it helped a lot, thanks.

Comment: Great, I am going to post an answer to remove this post from the unanswered list of questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code of symbols implemented in top-level can be seen by using [`PrintDefinitions`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78898/31159).

For `ShearingMatrix`, one can evaluate

```
<<GeneralUtilities`
PrintDefinitions[ShearingMatrix]
```

and then click on `` System`TransformConstructorDump`iShearingMatrix `` to view the formula used.

`PrintDefinitions` is available from version 10.1. For earlier versions of *Mathematica*, other spelunking tools can be found in this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1742/31159).