# Where is documentation for Control`PoleZeroPlot?

Tags: plotting, documentation, control-systems

An earlier question [here](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/382709?p_p_auth=Hsl4qSyo) mentioned `` Control`PoleZeroPlot ``, which I've found useful.  Typing `` Names["*`PoleZeroPlot] `` returns

```
{"Charting`PoleZeroPlot", "Control`PoleZeroPlot", "PoleZeroPlot"}
```

Mysteriously, when I type `PoleZeroPlot` into Mathematica, it knows nothing about it.  Digging around in the installation directories for Mathematica doesn't turn up any `Control` package.  Where can I find documentation on `PoleZeroPlot`?

Comment: Unfortunately not everything is documented, in which case if I can't find anything useful on MSE I typically have to make do by making educated guesses on how a function would work.

Comment: I'd like to see the source code, if nothing else.

Comment: Then you'll want to see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1742).

Comment: `Needs["GeneralUtilities'"]; PrintDefinitions[symbol];` pops up exactly what I need (version 11.0.1.0).  Thank you!