# What does the ToList function do, and where did it go?

Tags: list-manipulation, core-language

I am trying to revive some code from 2015 (version 10?) which uses the function `ToList`. I can not find it defined in any notebook on my system (in fact, it only appears in this one notebook). I had loaded the `GeneralUtilities` package in this notebook, so maybe `ToList` was defined in a previous version of that. From the context of its usage, it appears to force its arguments to be a list, but only if the argument is not already a list, like:

```
ToList[x_List] := x;
ToList[x__] := {x};
```

Does anybody remember this function?

Comment: @AlbertRetey There it is. I don't recall using the developer package. Thanks for finding it.

Comment: fwiw in 10.1 the symbol exists per ``?Developer`ToList`` but remains unevaluated for any argument.

Comment: ``GeneralUtilities`ToList`` existed in 10.0 and 10.1, but was moved into the `Developer` context in 10.2.  The `GeneralUtilities` version only accepted exactly one argument, but the `Developer` version accepts any number of arguments (including zero) and concatenates any explicit list arguments.

Comment: Fun fact that doesn't really add anything to WReach's comment in practice:  We can do `GeneralUtilities\`PrintDefinitions[Developer\`ToList]` (see [(1742)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78898/11035)) to see that the current version of `ToList` has only one definition yet accepts arbitrarily many arguments (including zero).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The function is still there (version 11.3). It lives in the `` Developer` `` context. If you don't know their context you can find functions with something like:

```
?*`ToList
```

or if they are in deeper nested contexts (e.g. private ones) with:

```
?*`*`To*
```

In that case the first one returns `` Developer`ToList ``. Of course that only works for those builtin symbols which are pre-loaded without an explict `Get` or `Needs`.

There is no documentation available, but some tests suggest that what you are guessing is correct:

```
Developer`ToList[x]
```

> {x}

```
Developer`ToList[{x}]
```

> {x}

```
Developer`ToList[{1,2,3}]
```

> {1,2,3}

```
Developer`ToList[1,2,3]
```

> {1,2,3}

Comment: I'll let this stew for a few days and accept your answer.

Comment: great, waiting for more answers is always a good idea...

Comment: Any idea what the purpose of this function is? In what case would it be used instead of, say, `Apply[List,f[1,2,3]]`, or just `List[1,2,3]`? (the reason this is nonobvious is maybe why it's not a global symbol)

Comment: @user6014 It might be useful in the implementation of functions like `Max` that take either a variable number of arguments (i.e., `Max[1, 2, 3]`) or a list of arguments (i.e., `Max[{1, 2, 3}]`). Pass the sequence of input arguments to `ToList`, and then either way, you've got a list you can process.