# Seeing definitions of built-in functions

Tags: variable-definitions, assignment

Possibly a very amateur question, so I'll apologise in advance. I'm reasonably new.

I'm trying to write a `Dot` equivalent of `ExpandDenominator`, i.e something that will have the capacity to write something like:

```
DotExpDen[1/(a+b)^2] = a.a + 2a.b + b.b
```

When using `ExpandDenominator/.Times->Dot`, it will correct the second cross-term but retain a<sup>2</sup> and b<sup>2</sup>.

I'm hoping to look at the internal workings of `ExpandDenominator`, and I'm sure this might be useful in the future for a variety of problems I'd encounter.

Is there a method to look at how Mathematica has implemented this in the back-end(?), like looking at a publicly available package?
I could probably do it in a `Module` of some kind, but I'm just looking for a general technique and perhaps look at their method and definitions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ExpandDenominator` is a kernel function that does not have a definition in the same sense as a function you write yourself. It is likely not implemented in the Wolfram Language internally.

Comment: Thank you for that link. It's not quite what I'm after, but your comment has clarified my question. I guess it's not possible to read how Mathematica implements like this then?

Comment: Not for *this* function; for others: use the techniques in the duplicate. The source files for certain functions of specific areas can be found in various placed in the `$InstallationDirectory`, e.g. most of the parallel tools sources are readable.

Comment: Specifically, I recommend this answer as a starting point: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78898/12

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Szabolcs. I appreciate your time! I have closed my question.