# Inspecting Mathematica object

Tags: core-language

I'm using `ProofObject` for my question, but it applies to other objects too.
`FindEquationalProof` returns `ProofObject` as a result:

```
proof = FindEquationalProof[a == c, {a == b, b == c}]
```

This example is taken from Mathematica's Help for `FindEquationalProof`.

The the Help article goes on with the following line:

```
proof["ProofDataset"]
```

When I look inside the proof object by `List@@prof` or by `proof//FullForm` I get this:

```
ProofObject[
  "EquationalLogic",
  a == c,
  a == b && b == c,
  {{"Axiom", 1} -> <|"Statement" -> b == a, 
    "Proof" -> <||>|>, {"Axiom", 2} -> <|"Statement" -> b == c, 
    "Proof" -> <||>|>, {"Hypothesis", 1} -> <|"Statement" -> a == c, 
    "Proof" -> <||>|>, 
       {"SubstitutionLemma", 1} -> <|"Statement" -> a == c, 
       "Proof" -> <|"Input" -> {"Axiom", 2}, "Position" -> 1, 
       "Construct" -> {"Axiom", 1}, "Orientation" -> 1, 
       "Rule" -> b -> a, 
       "OutputExpression" -> a == c|>|>, {"Conclusion", 
     1} -> <|"Statement" -> True, 
     "Proof" -> <|"Input" -> {"Hypothesis", 1}, "Position" -> 1, 
       "Construct" -> {"SubstitutionLemma", 1}, "Orientation" -> 1, 
       "Rule" -> a -> c, "OutputExpression" -> True|>|>}]
```

But there's no `"ProofDataset"` in this object.

In another question about `ColorDataFunction` I found the code for getting a list of property names and it worked for `ProofObject`:

```
proof["Properties"]
```

> {"Axioms", "Logic", "ProofDataset", "ProofFunction", "ProofGraph",
>   "ProofNotebook", "Theorem"}

And indeed `ProofDataset` is one of the property names.

I also tried `??ProofObject` but it also does not include any definitions for properties.

My question is: what kind of object is `ProofObject` and which introspection functions can I use to get its contents?

Why is it possible to do `proof["Properties"]` for this object? What happens under the hood?

Comment: If you want to see the definitions relating to `"ProofDataset"`, you can find them using the tools in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1742/9490)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"ProofDataset"` is a computed property of the `ProofObject`, it can be computed from the data inside the `ProofObject` but is not necessarily contained within the object.

Here is a simple toy example to demonstrate how this works:

`getMyObject` is a constructor, which creates a `MyObject`

```
getMyObject[{a_, b_}] := MyObject[<|"a" -> a, "b" -> b|>];
MyObject[assoc_]["ABSum"] := assoc["a"] + assoc["b"]
```

Now you can create this object and ask for it's "ABSum" property,

```
mo = getMyObject[{1, 2}]
(* MyObject[<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>] *)

mo["ABSum"]
(* 3 *)
```

Even though there are no rules inside of `mo` corresponding to `"ABSum"`, there are definitions on `MyObject` on how to compute it:

```
SubValues@MyObject
(* {HoldPattern[MyObject[assoc_]["ABSum"]] :> 
  assoc["a"] + assoc["b"]} *)
```