# Move definition from one context to Global`

Tags: variable-definitions, contexts

Suppose we have the following package `ABC.wl`.

```
BeginPackage["ABC`"]

Begin["DEF`"]

f1 = 0;
f2[x_] := x + 1

End[]

EndPackage[]
```

Using the package from a notebook yields the following definitions.

```
Needs["ABC`"]
In[1]:= Definition[DEF`f1]
Out[1]= DEF`f1 = 0
In[2]:= Definition[DEF`f2]
Out[2]= DEF`f2[DEF`x_] := DEF`x + 1
```

How can `` DEF`* `` be "moved" to `` Global` `` such that the definitions are of the same form as if they were defined in `` Global` ``?

```
In[1]:= Definition[f1]
Out[1]= f1 = 0
In[2]:= Definition[f2]
Out[2]= f2[x_] := x + 1
```

**Update**
Some motivation as requested by Szabolcs: this is useful e.g. when you want to print definitions from a context in a package without touching the source code of the package.

Comment: *Mathematica* will warn you if e.g. `f1` is present in both the ``ABC`​`` and ``Global`​`` contexts. Do you really want to have the same symbol for different contexts?

Comment: The context ```ABC` ``` could be removed after the definitions have been moved to ```Global` ``` to avoid the conflict.

Comment: If you really want this, you can do e.g. the following: ``Block[{$ContextPath = {"System`", "DEF`"}},  Scan[(Context[#] = "Global`") &, Names["DEF`*"]]]``. This will automatically make ``DEF` `` context empty, and it will be then automatically removed from a lit of available contexts, as per `Contexts[]`.

Comment: Thank you Leonid. If you like you can write it as an answer.

Comment: @Markus Done as requested.

Comment: Can you add some context and explain the motivation?

Comment: "when you want to print definitions from a context in a package without touching the source code of the package." - ah, you should see [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1742).

Comment: Very interesting, J.M. Thanks for the pointer. I do like Leonid's solution here because it is simple, elegant and serves simple purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want this, you can do e.g. the following:

```
Block[{$ContextPath = {"System`", "DEF`"}}, 
  Scan[
    (Context[#] = "Global`") &, 
    Names["DEF`*"]
  ]
]
```

Here, `Block` was used just to make sure that `Names` will return short symbol string names, rather than fully-qualified ones.

This will move all symbols from `` DEF` `` to `` Global` ``, which automatically make `` DEF` `` context empty, and it will be then automatically removed from a list of available contexts, as per `Contexts[]`.

Answer (score 3):

On my system, *Mathematica* 10.1 under Windows, I got an error using Leonid's code:

> Context::cxdup: Cannot set Context[DEF`x] to Global`, since a symbol already exists with name x and context Global`. >>

I seem to need something like this to avoid it:

```
Block[{$ContextPath = {"System`", "DEF`"}}, 
 Scan[(Quiet[Remove @@ {"Global`" <> StringTrim[#, __ ~~ "`"]}]; 
    Context[#] = "Global`") &, Names["DEF`*"]]]
```

Comment: Apparently, I have not considered the case when one or more of the symbols already exist in ``Global` ``, in which case one gets this error. Do you mind if I incorporate in some form your observation in my (updated) answer?

Comment: @Leonid No, of course I don't mind.  I thought in case this was a version difference I should post separately.