# Spelunking yields <<kernel function>>

Tags: implementation-details, contexts

This is in the spirit of the old but excellent thread: [What is the most convenient way to read definitions of in-memory symbols when we don't have the source files? (Spelunking tools)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1742/what-is-the-most-convenient-way-to-read-definitions-of-in-memory-symbols-when-we)

Using `` GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions `` I want to take a peek at the inner workings of `Solve`. However all I am able to see are the attributes and list of options. The function definition itself just shows up as `<<kernel function>>`. Does it mean that it is not written in Wolfram language itself and there are no Wolfram language primitives to express it, or is it somehow kept tightly under wraps?

Comment: Apart from perhaps some wrappers etc, it is very likely that the core implementation of `Solve` is NOT written in Wolfram Language, but instead implemented at a lower level.

Comment: I've always guess it's a bit of both, but I don't know, never asked WRI. `Trace[Solve[x^2 + x y == 1, x], TraceInternal -> True]` shows some of the code can be exposed, not enough to make complete sense of though.