# How do I remove the context from help messages

Tags: contexts

When using `??` I get the results which the context included. While technically accurate it makes the code difficult to read.

The following

```
Test[] := Module[{fi,fia,fib,fic,max}, 
            max=4;
            fi=FractionalIteration[f,n,z,0,max];
            fia=fi /. n->a;
            fib=fi /. n->b;
            fic=fi /. n->(a+b);
            Series[(fia /. z->fib)-fic,{z,0,max}]
        ];
```

becomes

```
Test[] := 
 Module[{FractionalIteration`Private`fi, 
   FractionalIteration`Private`fia, FractionalIteration`Private`fib, 
   FractionalIteration`Private`fic, FractionalIteration`Private`max}, 
  FractionalIteration`Private`max = 4; 
  FractionalIteration`Private`fi = 
   FractionalIteration[FractionalIteration`Private`f, 
    FractionalIteration`Private`n, FractionalIteration`Private`z, 0, 
    FractionalIteration`Private`max]; 
  FractionalIteration`Private`fia = 
   FractionalIteration`Private`fi /. 
    FractionalIteration`Private`n -> FractionalIteration`Private`a; 
  FractionalIteration`Private`fib = 
   FractionalIteration`Private`fi /. 
    FractionalIteration`Private`n -> FractionalIteration`Private`b; 
  FractionalIteration`Private`fic = 
   FractionalIteration`Private`fi /. 
    FractionalIteration`Private`n -> 
     FractionalIteration`Private`a + FractionalIteration`Private`b; 
  Series[(FractionalIteration`Private`fia /. 
      FractionalIteration`Private`z -> 
       FractionalIteration`Private`fib) - 
    FractionalIteration`Private`fic, {FractionalIteration`Private`z, 
    0, FractionalIteration`Private`max}]]
```

How can I get messages without the contexts?

Comment: I recommend to use ``GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions`` or ``GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitionsLocal`` to replace `??`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set

```
Internal`$ContextMarks = False;
```

will resolve the problem. (The default value of `` Internal`$ContextMarks `` is `Automatic` BTW. ) You may refer to the following post for more powerful tools:

[What is the most convenient way to read definitions of in-memory symbols when we don't have the source files? (Spelunking tools)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1742/1871)